# Equivalence of ANCOVA and repeated measures model

Tags: r, multiple-regression, repeated-measures, regression-coefficients, ancova

Consider an RCT with individuals *i* in 2 arms (*group*, with 0 = control and 1 = treatment) in which one metric outcome (*score*) is collected at baseline (*pre*) and after some treatment (*post*).

In an ANCOVA model, the two explanatory variables *pre* and *group* are mapped to the dependent variable *post* as follows:

$post_i ≈ a + b \cdot pre_i + c \cdot group_i$

Now, Van Breukelen (reference below) claims that ANCOVA is equivalent to testing the group by time interaction c' in the model

$score_{i,t} ≈ a' + b' \cdot time_{i,t} + c' \cdot group_i \cdot time_{i,t}$

with time = 0 denoting the pretest and time = 1 the posttest time point.

I tried to verify Van Breukelen's statement on a toy dataset in R:

```
# toy dataset
df_wide <- data.frame(
  "id" = 1:6,
  "group" = rep(c(0, 1), c(3, 3)),
  "pre" = c(2.4, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1, 3.9, 3.2),
  "post" = c(2.8, 4.2, 2.3, 3.8, 4.0, 4.3))

# first model (corresponds to ANCOVA except for the "grand mean")
summary(lm(post ~ pre + group, data = df_wide))
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)   2.7090     1.5362   1.763    0.176
#pre           0.1700     0.6354   0.268    0.806
#group         0.8030     0.8282   0.970    0.404

# reshaping data, ensuring correct coding of the time variable
df_long <- tidyr::pivot_longer(
  df_wide, cols = -c(id, group), names_to = "time", values_to = "score")
df_long$time <- 2 - as.numeric(as.factor(df_long$time))

# second model, supposed to be equivalent...
summary(lm(score ~ time + group:time, data = df_long))
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#(Intercept)   2.6833     0.2923   9.179 7.27e-06 ***
#time          0.4167     0.5063   0.823    0.432    
#time:group    0.9333     0.5847   1.596    0.145
```

Irritatingly, the coefficients for group (in the first model, *c* = 0.8030) and interaction (in the second model, *c'* = 0.9333) are different, and so are their *p* values. Am I misunderstanding something? Or did I misspecify the second model in R? How should I do it correctly? Can somebody maybe even demonstrate the two models' equivalence mathematically?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

*Reference*: Van Breukelen GJ. ANCOVA versus change from baseline: more power in randomized studies, more bias in nonrandomized studies [corrected]. J Clin Epidemiol. 2006 Sep;59(9):920-5. Erratum in: J Clin Epidemiol. 2006 Dec;59(12):1334.

Comment: I think the second model should be fitted as repeated measures anova. The authors do so themselves (page 922, second column, second paragraph from the top).

Comment: Thank you, COOLSerdash! I had already tried lmer(score ~ time + group:time + (1|id), data = df_long) but even that gave me slightly a different estimate (and p value). How would you write the repeated measures anova in R?

Comment: The second model gets you almost the same estimates and SEs if you include a random effect of id.
summary(lme4::lmer(score ~ time + group:time + (1|id), data = df_long))

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy! Your model is exactly the one that I mentioned one line above. The coefficients are somewhat close but not really close (0.6819  vs. 0.8030), and the _p_ values differ by a factor of 400 (0.000973  vs. 0.404). I don't think one could call those two models equivalent, and I still suspect that Van Breukelen meant something else...

Comment: This point is somewhat clarified in his 2013-paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00273171.2013.831743 As I understand it, the discrepancy should go down with increasing sample size if the treatment is randomized.

Comment: thank you, tormad. this is very helpful.